# R: rda() with CV

Tags: r, cross-validation, rda

I've used the following code:

```
breast.rda = rda(Diagnosis~ ., data=breast, lambda = 0.2, crossval=T, fold = 10, gamma=0)
```

I can retrieve the error by running:

```
breast.rda[5]
## $error.rate
##       APER 
## 0.06151142
```

But what does this error mean? How can I get only `0.06151142`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
breast.rda[[5]]
```

to extract the fifth list element. In contrast, the command `breast.rda[5]` returns a list of length one.